# AJAX / Postback Issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've been struggling for the whole weekend with unwanted postbacks.

The popup I'm working on has a button that basicaly fires a few stored procedures and then closes the pop up window.
What I wanted to achieve is to have the same result when people hit the X closing buton on the top right. 
So, X button = myCloseButton.

For that I've done this.

AJAX.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
var dataToSend = { MethodName: 'UpdateR' };
var options =
    {
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
    };
$.ajax(options);
});
```

.ASPX.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {   #region Ajax methods
              if (Request.Form["MethodName"] == "UpdateR")
              {
                  UpdateRegister();
                  return;
              }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And then `UpdateRegister()` executes the code that I want to execute once people leave the page.

So, the problem comes when people hit another(whatever) control inside the pop up page. The page enters the `(!IsPostBack)` and the AJAX method. That's understandable since I'm saying on `.unload` do this and that. (I've tried `$(window).bind('beforeunload', function()` and it's not working for the desired purpose)

Any idea on "How can I tell the page to difference when it's a closing event like X button or my control, and any other control on the page?" would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**. It's not something about serializing the form and comparing before leaving. No, it's about logins and stuff, so even if people open the pop up and close it immediately I need to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone gets here with an error something like this:

**Answer:**
All that was begin a mess in my webform was a button (an asp one). It was postbacking, so I disabled the postback via javascript and that was it. I'm now able to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you create WebMethod and directly call instead of calling via Page_Load() page event.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateRegister()
{
   // your update register script here
}
```

Sample call from jquery, you can call this ajax when someone click on load or unload button.

You can call ajax script when button with id "button1" clicked e.g

```
$(function(){
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    // close window
    window.close();
    // call ajax script to perform server side script

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Sample.aspx/UpdateRegister",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
      alert(msg.d);
    }
   });   
});
});
```

Comment: thanks for the input irfanmcsd, to be honest I've never worked with Webmethod's since I'm pretty new to this whole world of client side. Will read a bit about them and I'll try to implement this.

Comment: @irfanmcsd question: how will the popup window know when user hit X button? I can definetely call this webmethod from my ClosePageControl but how do I call it when users Close the Page via X button?. Because that's pretty mucho the problem I'm having with my original solution. Because if I call the webmethod when .unload it's gonna trigger all the time as it's happening right now.

Comment: When user click x button e.g x has id "button1" then you can use script to close popup and call ajax script to perform server side activities once popup closed, without effecting other actions within popup control